# How far do nether fortresses extend vertically?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'd like to build a spawning platform above the bedrock layer of the nether. If I build it over a nether fortress, will it continue to spawn wither skeletons?

Comment: No. They are programmed to spawn in a section of the map. You could configure this using MCEdit.

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that this will happen because nether fortresses never extend that far, unless you have some glitch.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to build a spawning platform above the bedrock layer of the nether. If I build it over a nether fortress, will it continue to spawn wither skeletons?

Um... No.
If you build your platform to go through parts of the fortress (at the height the ground of the walkway are on), then sort of; as in: Only the areas that go through the original position of the nether fortress will spawn the mobs.

---

The way nether mobs (other than Ghasts and Zombie Pigmen) such as Blazes, Wither/Regular Skeleton and Magma Cubes is that they spawn in specific regions within the Nether.

As for what those "specific regions" are, they are areas that are created during Nether Fortress Generation.
These areas do not extend to the borders of the chunk the Nether Fortress resides in, and they are made to only "fit"* the exact area the fortress resides in, meaning that they're anywhere from 15x15x8 (a 4-way intersection) to 7x5x7 (a single piece out of a long hallway) joined together as to how the fortress is laid out.

Mobs only spawn on a block if the block above it is within these regions.

*Exceptions apply with specific prefab sections of a Nether Fortress.

---

If you need some visualisation, this nifty video should clear things up by explaing how each "spawn region" covers each module of a Nether Fortress:

Note: Didn't really rewatch the video, so my numbers regarding areas may be wrong, but the general idea is still correct.